# Retrieve a New Relic report programatically

Tags: c#, rest, newrelic

I am trying to download New Relic data in a similar format to what you'd see at the following link, given a specified date range.

https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/(accountID)/applications/(applicationID)/transactions/table

[image: New Relic Web Transactions table]

I don't care whether the response is XML, JSON or CSV.

I've been struggling with the REST API for over a week.  I have it working, but it won't return the page paths and I can only request one value at a time which takes hours.

I looked into generating permalinks to the "Export as CSV" but that requires you to be in a UI session.

Does anyone have any pointers as to how I can programmatically download a table of Web Transaction data for an application and date range?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the REST API is the only path to get information like this, but you can make an API call that requests data for multiple 'agents' (used here to mean application names or instances in your New Relic user interface).

If you know the names of the web transactions that are interesting, it should be fairly easy to programmatically get metrics for those transactions over the same time period, just using a single call with multiple agents for each transaction.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to request multiple fields? I tried that only to receive the error "Only one field may be specified."

Comment: I apologize, you can request for multiple agents with a single API call but _not_ for multiple fields. You would need to make separate calls for each field, though you can use more than one agentID in each call.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I have far too many agents to specify them all at once (HTTP Protocol Violation).  I'll need to make this a bit more smart to work this out.